# Error when linking gtest project

Tags: c++, googletest, clion

recently I start study unit testing , and I want test my program with gtest. I install all with this order :

```
$ git clone https://github.com/google/googletest 
$ cd googletest 
$ cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON . 
$ make 
$ cd googlemock 
$ sudo cp ./libgmock_main.so ./gtest/libgtest.so gtest/libgtest_main.so ./libgmock.so /usr/lib/ 
$ sudo ldconfig
```

and now write code :

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class Add
{
  private:
     int element;
  public:
     Add():element(0){}
     ~Add(){}
     void setElement(int e){ element = e; }
     int getElement() { return element; }
     int adder(int e) { return element += e; }
};

class AddTest : public ::testing::Test
{
  protected:
       int abc(int a){
            return a;
        }

     virtual void SetUp(){
          add1.setElement(1);
          add2.setElement(20);
     }
     virtual void TearDown(){}

Add add1;
Add add2;
};

TEST_F(AddTest, getTest)
{
   EXPECT_EQ(1, add1.getElement());
   EXPECT_EQ(20, add2.getElement());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
   return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

end when I run test i get this error :

CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `AddTest_getTest_Test::TestBody()':
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to`testing::Message::Message()'
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(testing::TestPartResult::Type, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to`testing::internal::AssertHelper::operator=(testing::Message const&) const'
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to`testing::Message::Message()'
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(testing::TestPartResult::Type, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to`testing::internal::AssertHelper::operator=(testing::Message const&) const'
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to`testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/main.cpp.o: In function`main':
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:39: undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)'
CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/main.cpp.o: In function`__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)'
CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/main.cpp.o: In function`RUN_ALL_TESTS()':
/usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h:2235: undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()'
/usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h:2235: undefined reference to`testing::UnitTest::Run()'
CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `AddTest::AddTest()':
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to`testing::Test::Test()'
CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `AddTest::~AddTest()':
/home/artem/CLionProjects/mock2/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to`testing::Test::~Test()'
CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `testing::internal::scoped_ptr<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::reset(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
/usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1172: undefined reference to`testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)'
CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `testing::internal::scoped_ptr<std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::reset(std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
/usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1172: undefined reference to`testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)'
CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQ<int, int>(char const*, char const*, int const&, int const&)':
/usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h:1394: undefined reference to`testing::AssertionSuccess()'
CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<int, int>(char const*, char const*, int const&, int const&)':
/usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h:1384: undefined reference to`testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, bool)'
CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTI7AddTest[_ZTI7AddTest]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for testing::Test'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'mock2' failed
make[3]: *** [mock2] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/all' failed
make[2]:**  [CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/rule' failed
make[1]:  **[CMakeFiles/mock2.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'mock2' failed
make: *** [mock2] Error 2

but when use command

```
g++ main.cpp -o test -lgtest -lpthread
```

everytheng is good. How can I fix it and run it not in command line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CLion then you may have a CMakeLists.txt file you should add rules to link to the libraries. To do this add the following line to your CMakeLists.txt

```
enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED) # Find the google testing framework on your system
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${GTEST_LIBRARIES}) # Replace ${PROJECT_NAME} with your target name
```

For more details go [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindGTest.html).

Comment: New documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGTest.html